# How to trigger workflow when all files in PR are .csv

Tags: github, github-actions

I'd like to create a workflow in GitHub that triggers when **all** the changed files are .csv. I've been looking at [GitHub's workflow syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore) and I can only find instances where workflows are triggered when at least 1 certain file/directory is excluded or included.

My initial approach was

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '**.csv'
```

But this workflow will trigger as long as 1 file ends in .csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was running a workflow that tirggers when .csv files are added in the PR. Then a job starts that collects all the names of the files changed. Last it loops through the files changed and returns 'false' if any file doesn't end in .csv.

You can then add another job that uses the value of `needs.compare.outputs.compare`

```
name: csv-check

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '**'
    paths:
      - '**.csv'

jobs:
  changed_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      all: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.all }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
      - name: Get changed files
        id: changes
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=all::$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} ${{ github.sha }} | xargs)"
  compare:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: changed_files
    outputs:
      compare: ${{ steps.all_csv.outputs.compare }}
    if: ${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all }}
    steps:
      - name: echo changed files
        id: all_csv
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=compare::true"
          for file in ${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all }}; do
            if [[ $file != *.csv ]]; then
              echo "::set-output name=compare::false"
            fi
          done
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to review https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter - "GitHub Action that enables conditional execution of workflow steps and jobs, based on the files modified by pull request, on a feature branch, or by the recently pushed commits".